# overflow bloked scroll script

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a working script to hide and show a logo when the page reached certain scroll, when i applied overflow-x:hidden to the body and html to hide a blank space on the right side of the website the script stops working.

this is the script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logo").addClass("remove");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 300) {
        $("#logo").removeClass("remove");
      } else {
        $("#logo").addClass("remove");
      }
    });
  });
```

is there a way to hide the logo while keeping the css property of the body and html?

I would appreciate if someone guide me about that.

Comment: surely you should fix that space rather than hacking up your js

Comment: try changing the selector to `$("body").scroll`